# Object oriented programming: adding features on the fly

Tags: java, oop

I'm looking for an alternative to the decorator pattern to make it more dynamic. As a simplistic example, let's say we have this code:

```
interface Resource {
    public String getName();
}

interface Wrapper extends Resource {
    public Resource getSource();
}

interface Readable extends Resource {
    public InputStream getInputStream();
}

interface Listable extends Resource {
    public List<Resource> getChildren();
}



class File implements Readable {
    ...
}

class Zip implements Listable, Wrapper {
    public Zip(Readable source) { ... }
}
```

As you can see, Zip does not directly implement Readable, however the resource it is reading from does. Suppose we construct a zip:

```
Zip zip = new Zip(new File());
```

I don't want (and can't) stack all the interfaces to extend each other (e.g. Listable extends Readable), nor can I construct all the objects to implement all the features because not all features are related to one another, you want to be able to "decorate" objects on the fly by wrapping them.

I'm sure this is a common problem but is there a pattern to solve it? Using the "Wrapper" interface you can of course probe the chain of resources to check for features if you want but I'm not sure if this is a sane approach.

**UPDATE**

The problem is as stated above that not all features are related so you can't build a nice hierarchy of interfaces. For example suppose you have this arbitrary new feature:

```
interface Rateable extends Resource {
    public int getRating();
}

class DatabaseRateable implements Rateable, Wrapper {
    public DatabaseRateable(Resource resource) { ... }
}
```

If you run:

```
Resource resource = new DatabaseRateable(new Zip(new File));
```

The resulting resource has "lost" all the features (readable, listable,...) that were added.
It would be ridiculous to have Rateable extend say Listable.

Once again I could recursively check resource.getSource() and find out all the features. In the immediate replies there was no clear solution so perhaps the recursive check is a good option after all?

Comment: To what end are you decorating the objects?

Comment: Why can't `Zip` also implement `Readable`?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example where this is a problem?

Comment: @Dai example provided in the update

Comment: @flup To add features on the fly to objects that have no knowledge that such features even exist.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Not all features are related so there is no clear hierarchy possible (see update for an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will offer my own suggestion (as presented in the original question) as an answer. If enough people think it a worthy solution or a better solution is not forthcoming, I will accept it.

In short, my own solution consists of using the Wrapper interface to walk backwards through the resources to figure out which features are present. Given the example:

```
Resource resource = new DatabaseRateable(new Zip(new File));
```

You could imagine doing this:

```
public Readable asReadable(Resource resource) {
    if (resource instanceof Readable)
        return (Readable) resource;
    else if (resource instanceof Wrapper)
        return (asReadable( ((Wrapper) resource).getSource() );
    else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it sounds to me like the concept your striving for here is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which java itself does not do natively (see my comment about a reflection-based java library for this). however, other languages running on the JVM certainly do. for example - [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/):

```
class Duck {
    quack() { println "I am a Duck" }
}

class Frog {
    quack() { println "I am a Frog" }
}

quackers = [ new Duck(), new Frog() ]
for (q in quackers) {
    q.quack()
}
```

you could write your code in groovy and have it seamlessly work alongside the rest of your java code, and solve this issue in groovy.

Comment: While interesting, groovy is not an option and strict typing is a must.

Comment: @user1109519 - in that case you might consider using a library for duck-typing in java - http://code.google.com/p/duckapter/.

be aware that it uses reflection, but unless youre calling these things in a tight loop that shouldnt affect you too much

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for are [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)

The linked wikipedia page has a good list of OOP languages that support them.  Or are you specifically tied to Java?

Comment: Runtime mixins (as opposed to compile time) could provide a solution, I am however very much tied to java

Comment: There is a mixin implementation for java, see [Qi4j](http://qi4j.org/latest/ten-minutes-intro.html). It constructs Composites from Fragments. It may be a somewhat heavyweight solution for your purpose, though.

Comment: @flup If I understand the framework correctly, Qi4j is not "dynamic" in that the composites and such must be compiled. The features are however entirely dynamic and should not require rebuilds to function.

Comment: @user1109519 it is! (assuming I understand you correctly) See the [intro](http://qi4j.org/latest/intro.html). "The composition of the object may change over time."

Answer (score 0):

When decorating an object, you usually decorate one interface of the object only, to modify or add only one aspect of its behavior.
You can decorate another interface of the object with a different decorator. These decorators can exist at the same time.

You can pass one decorator to one method, the other to another.

This gets hacky when you wish to decorate the object first with several decorators and then pass the object around through your code.

So for your case, I'd suggest you wrapper the decorators into one single object again, which knows what kind of decorators exist for resources.

```
class Resource {
    private Readable readable; 
    private Listable listable;
    private Rateable rateable;

    setReadable(Readable readable) {
        this.readable = readable;
    }

    setListable(Listable listable) {
        this.listable = listable;
    }

    setRateable(Rateable rateable) {
        this.rateable = rateable;
    }

    public boolean isRateable(){
        return rateable != null;
    }

    public Rateable getRateable(){
        return rateable;
    }
    // etc
}

File file1 = new File();
Resource resource = new Resource(file1);
resource.setReadable(new ReadableFile(file1));
resource.setListable(new ListableFile(file1));
resource.setRateable(new DatabaseRateableFile(file1));
```

You can then pass around the resource and its users can discover which features this particular resource has.

The [Qi4j framework](http://qi4j.org/latest/ten-minutes-intro.html) allows you to do this (and more) in a cleaner way, using annotations. You compose Fragments into Composites. It does take some getting used to, though. The advantage of rolling your own specific implementation for Resources is that it'll be easier to explain to others.

Comment: The problem is that the initial object does not implement the features. The features are added (and they themselves can be decorated). The decorator pattern assumes you simply override existing methods, not essentially add them on the fly.

Comment: *rereads* Not entirely true, you can add behavior too using a decorator.

Comment: Yes but if you add behavior, the resulting decorator is still meant to implement all the methods of the already existing behavior, at which point it becomes untenable. The problem is indeed that I want to pass a decorated object around.

Comment: You need not implement all of the other methods in the decorator. What type will the resulting object have? And will you often decorate the object in the same way?

Comment: It does if you want to access said methods using the decorated object. The resulting object is mostly a resource which is probed for specific features when needed. There are a myriad of features in all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) can help:

```
Readable r = zip.adapt( Readable.class );
```

This asks the method `adapt()` to return an instance of `zip` which implements the `Readable` interface.

The implementations usually uses an "adapter manager" which knows how to build wrappers for all registered types.

Comment: While the adapter pattern could possibly do the trick code-wise, the pattern itself is (in my opinion) not designed for it. It is meant to translate features that are alike but with different interfaces to one another. The problem at hand is entirely new, unrelated features. You could "adapt" a Zip to Readable but I think it strays too far from the intent of the pattern to call it that.

Comment: Code design is always a choice between contradicting goals. When you insist on a "pure and clean" solution, then the answer is: It can't be done. Java simply doesn't have the tools. So you must accept some workaround. The adapter pattern is flexible enough to do what you need while it clearly communicates intent. That the pattern documentation doesn't mention this use case isn't an argument against the use because the documentation can be wrong.

Comment: Entirely true, my own solution (see original question or my own answer) follows the same stategem (casting to what you need) but does it without an actual adapter. As such it diverges too far from said pattern.

Comment: The Pattern whose intent you're looking for is the Bridge http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Science/Design_Patterns/Bridge_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Here maybe not so fitting, but a dynamic feature discovery:

```
public class Features {

    public <T> lookup(Class<T> intface) 
            throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        return lookup(intface, intface.getSimpleName());
    }

    public <T> lookup(Class<T> intface, String name) 
            throws UnsupportedOperationException {
        return map.get(...);
    }
}

public class X {
    public final Features FEATURES = new Features();
    ...
}

X x;
Readable r = x.FEATURES.lookup(Readable.class);
```